# How to mask columns with some nan values, using regular expressions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column of boroughs visited (among many other columns):

```
Index  User     Boroughs_visited
0      Eminem   Manhattan, Bronx
1      BrSpears NaN
2      Elvis    Brooklyn
3      Adele    Queens, Brooklyn
```

**I want to create a third column that shows which User visited Brooklyn**, so I wrote the slowest code possible in python:

```
df['Brooklyn']= 0
def borough():
    for index,x in enumerate(df['Boroughs_visited']):
        if pd.isnull(x):
            continue
        elif re.search(r'\bBrooklyn\b',x):
            df_vols['Brooklyn'][index]= 1

borough()
```

Resulting in:

```
Index  User     Boroughs_visited  Brooklyn
0      Eminem   Manhattan, Bronx   0
1      BrSpears NaN                0
2      Elvis    Brooklyn           1
3      Adele    Queens, Brooklyn   1
```

**It took my computer 15 seconds to run this for 2000 rows. Is there a faster way of doing this?**

Comment: I tried already but i get: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: for the record... if you wanted to slow it down further `from time import sleep; sleep(10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let use `.str` accessor with `contains` and `fillna`:

```
df['Brooklyn'] = (df.Boroughs_visited.str.contains('Brooklyn') * 1).fillna(0)
```

Or another format of the same statement:

```
df['Brooklyn'] = df.Boroughs_visited.str.contains('Brooklyn').mul(1, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   Index          User  Boroughs_visited  Brooklyn
0      0        Eminem  Manhattan, Bronx         0
1      1  BrSpears NaN              None         0
2      2         Elvis          Brooklyn         1
3      3         Adele  Queens, Brooklyn         1
```

Comment: thank you, indeed, it worked. But can you please explain this to me so I can learn. How does it know to assign a zero when Brooklyn is not there? Is it a boolean that assigns 1 if True and 0 if False?

Comment: If you run that statement, and omit the fillna(0) and * 1 you will see that it returns False, None, True, True.  then multiply * 1 to convert to integer and the NaN stays, then I use `fillna` to assign 0.  False * 1 = 0,  None  * 1 = NaN and ofcourse True * 1 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all Boroughs for the price of one

```
df.join(df.Boroughs_visited.str.get_dummies(sep=', '))

   Index      User  Boroughs_visited  Bronx  Brooklyn  Manhattan  Queens
0      0    Eminem  Manhattan, Bronx      1         0          1       0
1      1  BrSpears               NaN      0         0          0       0
2      2     Elvis          Brooklyn      0         1          0       0
3      3     Adele  Queens, Brooklyn      0         1          0       1
```

But if you really, really just wanted Brooklyn

```
df.join(df.Boroughs_visited.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').Brooklyn)

   Index      User  Boroughs_visited  Brooklyn
0      0    Eminem  Manhattan, Bronx         0
1      1  BrSpears               NaN         0
2      2     Elvis          Brooklyn         1
3      3     Adele  Queens, Brooklyn         1
```

Comment: thanks @piRSquared What's the reason you have to join the df before getting dummies?

Comment: @AdamSchroeder the get_dummies produces a dataframe with columns for each unique value in the Boroughs_visited column.  I wanted that generated dataframe adjacent to the original.  The `join` takes care of that.  For the single column example... I could have assigned the results with `df['Brooklyn] = df.Boroughs_visited.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').Brooklyn` or `df.assign(Brooklyn=df.Boroughs_visited.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').Brooklyn)`

Comment: Now I get it. It's cool that it's 14.9998 seconds faster than my original solution. Thank you